# Anyline MRZ Scanner shows wrong dob in my Android project

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development. I am working on one Android project using Anyline MRZ scanner for scanning passport but it shows the wrong year of DOB means if I scanned passport which has a dob 19-10-1978 after scanning it shows DOB(19-10-0078). Could anybody help me to fix this problem

```
// code of SCAN MRZ ACTIVITY
        DateFormat dateFormat =android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getApplicationContext()); 
    LinkedHashMap identificationResult = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
    if (identification.getDayOfBirthObject() == null) {
     if (identification.getDayOfBirth() != null && (!identification.getDayOfBirth().isEmpty())) 
     { 
     identificationResult.put(getResources().getString(R.string.mrz_date_of_birthday), getResources().getString(R.string.not_valid)); 
     }
     else { identificationResult.put(getResources().getString(R.string.mrz_date_of_birthday), getResources().getString(R.string.not_available)); }
     } else {
      identificationResult.put(getResources().getString(R.string.mrz_date_of_birthday), dateFormat.format(identification.getDayOfBirthObject()));
      }
```

Comment: Could you show us, what you have programmed.

Comment: ok I have edited